# Create JSON object Dynamically via JavaScript/C#

Tags: c#, javascript

I have JSON Data

```
var obj=fields: {
ProductName: { type: "string" },
UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
       .
       .
       .
     n number of properties
```

}

Actual problrm with me is that fields can have n number of property.Can anybody please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can create n number of properties. what is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am new to JSON that's why I don't know how to create.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop it:

```
var obj = {
    fields: {
        ProductName: {
            type: "string"
        },
        UnitPrice: {
            type: "number"
        },
        UnitsInStock: {
            type: "number"
        },
        Discontinued: {
            type: "boolean"
        }
    }
};

var n = 100;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    obj.fields["prop" + i] = {type: "string"};
}

console.log(obj);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h52hdaq9/)**